# How do I make a character controller in Roblox that mimics the physics and controls of Super Mario Sunshine?

Tags: lua, controls, roblox

I'm making a game. Not just any game though, it's gonna be my biggest game EVER. Super Tropical Blox is the name of the game. It's gonna be like Mario Sunshine, but in Roblox! There's just one problem though... I have literally no idea how to make a character controller.

I know games like Robot 64 have character controllers similar to Mario games, but I feel like they're all too floaty and low-gravity. I want to make my game feel as close to Sunshine as possible. Also, I just feel lazy and stupid using open-source games.

I put this here because people on Stack Overflow tend to be smarter than regular people on the DevForum (no offense), and because the way to "level up" in DevForum is the stupidest thing I've ever seen.

I tried using a part with VectorForces and a LocalScript communicating to the server, but I hated it and deleted it. I probably should have copy-pasted the script so I can put it here, but I lost it. I also tried using a regular humanoid, but it felt too... un-mario-ish?

If nobody solves this (and, they probably won't because I don't have a script here) I have a backup Input and Movement script in StarterCharacterScripts.

Here is the LocalScript:

```
wait(2)
doact = script.Parent.Script.DoAction --I should put this in ReplicatedStorage :/
uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")
uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(key)
    if key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Z then
        j = script.Parent.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(script.Animation)
        j.Priority = Enum.AnimationPriority.Action
        j:Play()
        doact:FireServer("Dive")
        wait(0.7)
        repeat wait() until script.Parent.Humanoid.StateChanged
        j:Stop()
    end
    if key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E then
        doact:FireServer("FLUDD")
    end
    if key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Q then
        doact:FireServer("FLUDDswap")
    end
    if key.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.LeftControl then
        doact:FireServer("Crawl")
    end
end)
```

Here is the Script:

```
VectorForce = script.Parent.HumanoidRootPart.VectorForce
HRootPart = script.Parent.HumanoidRootPart
script.DoAction.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, action)
    print(action)
    if action == "Dive" then
        script.Parent.Humanoid.Sit = true
        VectorForce.Force = HRootPart.CFrame.LookVector * 1500 + Vector3.new(0,100,0)
        script.Disabled = true
        wait(0.7)
        script.Disabled = false
        script.Parent.Humanoid.Sit = false
        VectorForce.Force = Vector3.new()
    end
end)
```

I want to use a ModuleScript for the movements so my script isn't so cluttered up. These scripts are WIP.

Did I just start every paragraph with the letter I?

Comment: Heyo, you should try to solve this problem first before asking here. Writing a character controller is fairly complex and until you get into it, you won't know what questions are important to ask. So give it a shot, and when you get stuck, come back and let us know what you tried and what isn't working.

Comment: @Kylaaa alright, my 2 attempts are in the question now.